# Problem in fetching the value from the database in android

Tags: java, android, database

in my application i am using the sql server database to store and retrieve the value from the database. Now i am fetching each row and add "~" between each column data. And at the time of calling the function i split it with the same(~). Now my problem is if some of the field is blank in the database so i didn't return space so how can i manage the blank data to display in the write place. I am quite new for that. If know one can understand the scenario feel free to ask. thank u.

```
//Function Definition
public String[] selectPhoneDirectory(String siteId){
    String[] detailofemployee = new String[25];
    openConnection();
    String query = "Select * from Telephone_master with(nolock) where Site_ID = '"+siteId+"' order by User_Name";
    int i =0;
    try{
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            detailofemployee[i] = rs.getString(3)+"~"+rs.getString(4)+"~"+rs.getString(5)+"~"+rs.getString(6)+"~"+rs.getString(7);
            System.out.println("The Detail Is :"+detailofemployee[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error!!!"+e);
    }
    closeConnection();
    return detailofemployee;
}

//Calling Function

for(int i = 0; i < siteName.length; i++){
    if(siteName[i].equalsIgnoreCase(strselectedName)){
        detailEmployee = gd.selectPhoneDirectory(siteId[i]);

    }
    for(int j = 0 ;j < detailEmployee.length ; j++){
    StringTokenizer st =new StringTokenizer(detailEmployee[j]);
        empName[j] = new String();
        empName[j] = st.nextToken("~").toString();
        System.out.println("The Name Is :"+empName[j]);

        empHome[j] = new String();
        empHome[j] = st.nextToken("~").toString();      
        System.out.println("The Home No Is :"+empHome[j]);

        empMob[j] = new String();
        empMob[j] = st.nextToken("~").toString();  
        System.out.println("The Mobile No Is :"+empMob[j]); 

        }
```

Comment: I have attach the link where the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myStr =yourTableRaw ;
```

use the `replaceAll` method

this replace the consecutive ~ with one ~ character

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("~+","~");
```

then make the splite call

```
String result []= myStr.split("~");
```